# how to display a particular string in color in pop up alert in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I would like to display a particular text in color in the pop up alert box message in a Java script.
For example:

```
function redirect()
{
  if ERCode == 'TEST' 
  {
    alert("You will be redirected to www.google.com.");
  }
}
```

I want www.google.com to be displayed in Blue color when the pop alert comes. 
Is this possible in Java Script?

Is it possible to underline atleast a string?

Comment: Why there is a `php` tag ?

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not possible with `alert`.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do it using the default popup dialog. You'll need to use something like http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Comment: Is it possible to underline a particular string?

Comment: yeah, you can customize the content of the dialog using standard HTML.

Comment: So how to do that? I need only the www.google.com part underlined and in different color text

Comment: Click on "View Source" link on this http://jqueryui.com/dialog/ page. They give you a complete example.  you can either put that link in an "HREF" tag OR you can use standard CSS formatting to format it.

Answer (score 0):

You can't, the alert box uses what ever color the browser developers set it to.

The only way to to get a custom colored alert box is to create your own and write the code for it. An example of a [custom html alert](http://slayeroffice.com/code/custom_alert/) that adds no dependencies. I haven't tested that code but it seems like it would work.

Comment: What does this talk about? 

http://bytes.com/topic/javascript/answers/477809-formatting-text-javascript-popup-boxes

Comment: @Ditty: yes, it talks exactly about that. Or do you have a more specific question?

Answer (score 0):

Using jQuery and jQuery UI.

```
var dialogUI = $( '<p>You text here <a href="http://google.com">google.com</a></p>' ).dialog( {
   modal: true,
   title: 'Alert',
   buttons: {
      'Okay': function() {
         dialogUI.dialog( 'destroy' );
         // code going to google here
      }
   }
} );
```

Comment: I am using the above JS in php. So for Jquery to work what should be done?

Comment: @Ditty goto the jQuery website and follow the installation instructions for jQuery and jQuery UI. Once you have done it you will wonder how you ever got along without it :)

Comment: how to copy the JQueryUI? It looks like it is a zip file.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible in alert but using `jQuery` (there are other libraries too) you can  achieve this, i.e.

```
function redirect()
{
    if ERCode == 'TEST' 
    {
        $('<div/>', {'html':'You will be redirected to <span style="color:blue">www.google.com.</span>'})
       .dialog({
            width:400,
            height:'auto',
            modal:true,
            resizable:false,
            buttons: {  
                "Ok":function(){
                    //$(this).dialog("close"); 
                    window.location='www.google.com';
                 } 
             }
         });
    }
}
```

[**Example Here.**](http://jsfiddle.net/ThH6d/1/) or [**This One**](http://jsfiddle.net/ThH6d/2/).

Comment: @dqhendricks, Sorry but I think it's a bit different and trust me I didn't see your answer.

Comment: BTW I am using the JS in php. So does it matter? Do I need to add something for the above jQuery to work?

Comment: @Ditty, yes, you need to add [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) and [jQuery-ui](http://jqueryui.com/).

Comment: @SheikhHeera - I am new to this.. Can you please help how to go about it? So I download these two .js and add it to the path in my page?

Comment: @Ditty, [check this](http://jsfiddle.net/NSZsm/), add link and script tags and put the given function in a script tag.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21349/discussion-between-ditty-and-sheikh-heera)

Comment: @SheikhHeera -- How are we getting the html or text as you have shown in your example? 

    $('<div/>', {'html':'You will be redirected to <span style="color:blue">www.. 

Do we need to define any DIV?

Comment: @Ditty, `'html':'goes hers'`

Comment: @SheikhHeera -- Did you misspell here to hers?

Comment: @SheikhHeera -- So here means where? I am sorry :-)

Comment: See the example I wrote `'html':'html goes here'`.